# $x^3-bx^2+4hx-ph=0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cubics

$$x^3-bx^2+4hx-ph=0$$

Taking the equation above, is there away to prove that for every positive prime p:

There are positive integer values for b and h so that the cubic has 3 positive integer roots

Or 2 positive integer roots with one being repeated.

Intuitively, it is obvious that this is the case and to help visualize it graphically I used desmos. Looking at specific cases of primes is fine, however I am not sure how to go about the general case.

Even proving that there are always 2 or 3 positive rational roots would be helpful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your cubic has 3 real roots, $kp, m, n \text{ with } k,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, so that

$$\begin{align*}f(x)&= (x-kp)(x-m)(x-n) \\
\\
&= x^3-(kp+m+n)x^2+\left(kpm + kpn +mn\right)x-kpmn \\
\\
&= x^3-bx^2+4hx-ph
\end{align*}$$

Which yields

$$\begin{align*}b &= kp+m+n\\
h &= kmn\\
4h &= kp(m+n) +mn\\
\end{align*}$$

So your conjecture is equivalent to the following statement about how every prime, $p$, must be able to be expressed with $ k,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\begin{align*} p&=\dfrac{(4k-1)mn}{k(m+n)}\\
\\
p&= \left(4-\dfrac{1}{k}\right)\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{m}+\dfrac{1}{n}}
\end{align*}$$

If you can prove every positive prime can be expressed like that, then your conjecture is true.